# Wifi stopped working after update to 22.04

Tags: networking, kernel

I updated Ubuntu to 22.04 which made the wifi quit working in my laptop. It did not even show up at all.
I found that lshw -class network showed the wifi card but it also said network unclaimed. I then booted into kernal 15.3 instead of 15.5 through grub and found that the wifi is now working! So how do i "fix" the wifi in 15.5? Or should i just stay in kernal 15.3?

The wifi card is on pci and the specific card is a Intel AX201.

Putting in `uname -r` in terminal gives me *5.15.0-40-generic*, and `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` gives me *Status: install ok installed*

Comment: Stay for the moment, keep updating regularly as you should do. At some point a newer kernel will correct that regression.

Comment: Please reboot into 5.15 where the wireless is not working and run: `uname -r` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Write down the result. Reboot into 5.13 where the wireless *does* work and then edit your question to include the results you noted. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe we should now what is the wireless device? Is it a USB or a PCI device?

Comment: While booted into 5.15, please do: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and note any errors or warnings. If none, then run: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and edit your question to include the result.

Answer (score 1):

`$ sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04`
as suggested here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/705739 solved the issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).